# program to view multiple images as a multi page document

Tags: software-recommendation, okular, image-viewers

I'd like to view multiple JPEG images (scans) like a PDF. If I open one in gwenview, it displays them fitting into the screen, and I cannot really scroll. If I open them in okular, it displays them just like I'd like, but I can't open multiple images [and that is not going to change](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183102).

Is there any other program out there that might “simulate” a multi page PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why simulate? Why not put them all into one pdf file?

```
convert *.jpg my_new.pdf
```

to readjust images there see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/147806/47206)

Comment: This is what I finally ended up doing, since my own `multiimage` approach was not portable and to cumbersome. Also, I realized it does not make sense to copy functionality that a PDF viewer already offers.

Answer (score 1):

[multiimage](https://github.com/martin-ueding/multiimage) displays multiple images as one multi-page document.